# Get QR code version number from Zxing library

Tags: java, zxing

Is any possible way to get the decoded QR code version number (maybe version 1,2,3...40) in zxing? (Not android)

I found a class name called Version.java in [com.google.zxing.qrcode.decoder](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/tree/master/core/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/qrcode/decoder) package, but I have no idea how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
QRCode qrcode = com.google.zxing.qrcode.encoder.Encoder.encode(content, errorCorrectionLevel);

int qrCodeVersion = qrcode.getVersion().getVersionNumber();
```

Edit: Updated to show how to obtain the QRCode

Comment: I get your point. But the QRCodeWriter.encode only able to return BitMatrix. How am I get the QRCode?

Comment: I read from a post in github that ECL and raw bytes can compute the version but no actual algo.